# Unable to retrieve Textbox value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to Jquery, apologize if this is wrong way

I have a template array in which I'm trying to add the CallerName as per the text entered in the CallerName Textbox in the form.

```
Var template_content=[
"Hello" CallerName,"\n \n" + "This is the dummy template 1".,
"Hello" CallerName,"\n \n" + "This is the dummy template 2".,
"Hello" CallerName,"\n \n" + "This is the dummy template 3".,
]
```

With the below jquery code, I'm able to get the CallerName Textbox value in alertbox,

```
var cname = $("[name='inc.caller_Name']");
var CallerName= cname.val();
//alert(CallerName)
```

Below is the click function

```
$(".dropdown a").click(function(){
        var index=parseInt($(this).attr("index"));  
         var notes = $("[name='inc.comm']");
         notes.html(template_content[index]);
         
        $("#ac-textarea").html(template_content[index]); 
    });
```

So my issue is I get the CallerName value correctly in alertbox but in the template, CallerName is blank.

Comment: it appears that the `template_content` is being created before the CallerName is filled from the textbox value

Comment: Could you suggest how to fix that. I tried adding CallerName within the click function, that would not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi sharon can you try with `val(template_content[index])` instead of html